# Brent's method in the R optim implementation always returns the same local minimum

Tags: r, optimization

[image: Function to be minimised]

I'm trying to minimise the function shown above. I'm searching between (-1,1). I use the following code

```
optim(runif(1,min=-1,max=+1), ..., method = "Brent", lower = -1.0, upper = 1.0)
```

and I've noticed that it always returns a value of x = -0.73 instead of the correct x = 0.88 answer. The reason is given in the `optimise` help page:

> The first evaluation of f is always at x_1 = a + (1-φ)(b-a) where (a,b) = (lower, upper) and phi = (sqrt(5) - 1)/2 = 0.61803.. is the golden section ratio. Almost always, the second evaluation is at x_2 = a + phi(b-a). Note that a local minimum inside [x_1,x_2] will be found as solution, even when f is constant in there, see the last example.

I'm curious if there is anyway to use Brent's method without hitting the same local minimum each time.

Changing method to "L-BFGS-B" works better (a random local minimum is returned each time):

```
optim(runif(1,min=-1,max=+1), ..., method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = -1.0, upper = 1.0)
```

Comment: What is your function?

Comment: voting to migrate to Stack Overflow (this is a programming/optimization/R question, not a stats question ...)

Comment: Ben Bolker, I still think there is methodology question on  convexity and optimization vs purely programming question.

Comment: This is a _utility_ function in an active machine learning problem. The minimum corresponds to the most _useful_ sample to acquire next. The function has interesting shapes because it depends on what data has been observed already.

Comment: Flipping the function about 0 should work in this case. Better would be to split the region at/near the maximum and solve the min problem in each subregion. More broadly, you should use optimization methods more suited to the style of problem you have. Brent is not a suitable choice to find the global optimum when there's more than a *single* local optimum in the interval. Since it's deterministic it will necessarily always find the same one.

Comment: I still don't understand which part of the question is a programming question and why it was moved to stackoverflow. The question clearly asks for a methodological question related to optimization in machine learning. It should be moved back to cross validated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is NOT convex,  therefore you will have multiple local/global minima or maxima. For your function I would run a non traditional/ derivative free global optimizer like simulated annealing or genetic algorithm and use the output as a starting point for BFGS or any other local optimizers to get a precise solution. Repeat the above step multiple times you will find all the global and local optimum points.

Comment: I believe the first sentence is badly phrased - or how can you have multiple global minima?

Comment: @foobar Consider, for example, the (countably infinitely many) global maxima and mimima of $\sin$ or $\cos$.